# Prevent a Border control from shrinking when its child controls shrink

Tags: maui, .net-maui

I have a `Border` control that contains a couple of `Label` controls. The text shown in the labels changes, and this causes the `Border` control to expand and shrink horizontally. To prevent flickering, I want it to be able to expand but not shrink. Is there a way to do this?

Alternatively, is there a way to specify that the `Label` objects should expand horizontally but never shrink - which would give the same outcome?

My XAML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="uk.andyjohnson.TakeoutExtractor.Gui.ProgressOverlay">
    <Border
        Stroke="#0f0f0f"
        StrokeThickness="2"
        StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 5,5,5,5"
        HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
        Padding="30,30">
        <VerticalStackLayout
            Spacing="25" >

            <Label 
                x:Name="SourceLabel"
                Text=""
                HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
            <Label 
                x:Name="DestinationLabel"
                Text=""
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </Border>
</ContentView>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem using a variation on Riccardo Minato's suggestion.

1. Hook into the `SizeChanged` event on the bounding `Border` object.
2. Track its maximum width using a member variable
3. When the width exceeds the previous maximum, set the `Border` object's `MinimumWidthRequest` property to the new maximum width. This stops it shrinking.

New XAML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="uk.andyjohnson.TakeoutExtractor.Gui.ProgressOverlay">
    <Border
        Stroke="#0f0f0f"
        StrokeThickness="2"
        StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 5,5,5,5"
        HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
        Padding="30,30"
        SizeChanged="Border_SizeChanged">  <!-- ** Added this line ** -->
        <VerticalStackLayout
            Spacing="25" >
            <ActivityIndicator
                IsVisible="true"
                IsRunning="true"
                IsEnabled="true"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
            <Button
                x:Name="CancelButton"
                Text="Cancel"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                Clicked="OnCancelButtonClicked"/>
            <Label 
                x:Name="SourceLabel"
                Text=""
                HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
            <Label 
                x:Name="DestinationLabel"
                Text=""
                HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </Border>
</ContentView>
```

New code-behind:

```
private double currentMaxWidth = 0D;

private void Border_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var bdr = sender as Border;
    if (bdr.Width > currentMaxWidth)
    {
        currentMaxWidth = bdr.Width;
        bdr.MinimumWidthRequest = currentMaxWidth;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could play with labels `WidthRequest`.
When your label increase in size, you set its `WidthRequest` to its current `Width` value.

Assuming for simplicity that you're changing the label text in your code-behind and that there is only one label, something like this should do the job.

```
public partial class ProgressOverlay
{
     private double currentWidth = 0;

     // I create this method just to explain.
     // It could be anything in your code that changes your label text
     void ChangingText()
     {
         // ******
         // .... SourceLabel text changes here ...
         // *******

         if (SourceLabel.Width > currentWidth)
         {
             SourceLabel.WidthRequest = SourceLabel.Width;
             currentWidth = SourceLabel.Width;
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Your post helped me to solve this. In the end I adapted your approach to produce a slightly different solution. I hooked into the `SizeChanged` event on the bounding `Border` object, tracked its maximum width using a member variable, and when the width exceeded the previous maximum I set the `Border` object's `MinimumWidthRequest` property to the new maximum width. This stops it shrinking.